QuerySelector returns null even though page has completely rendered
I am querying a complex page that is using custom HTML elements with standard HTML elements. The page has completely loaded and I can see the HTML within "elements" tab when inspecting the page.
HTML (simplified)
<dl class="slds-form">
 <slot class="slds-grid slds-size_1-of-1">
  ...
 </slot>
</dl>

Ran below JS in console
document.querySelector('.slds-form');

Returned is null
Is it not possible to query non-standard HTML element?
It is strange. Even when I query standard html elements like div, it returns null
For example, I can clearly see the below when inspecting the page:
<span class="test-id__field-value slds-form-element__static slds-grow">
 ...
</span>

Ran below JS in console
document.querySelector('span.test-id__field-value.slds-form-element__static.slds-grow word-break-ie11');

Returned is null
Edit:
As explained, this is a complex page. I have queried down to the element that is causing me the issue and it looks like this. I cannot query below this element:
<forcegenerated-adg-rollup_component___force-generated__flexipage_-record-page>
...
   <dl class="slds-form">
    <slot class="slds-grid slds-size_1-of-1">
     ...
    </slot>
   </dl>
...
</forcegenerated-adg-rollup_component___force-generated__flexipage_-record-page>

I cannot query children below <forcegenerated...

Is that HTML in an iframe or something? Normally, it should work

It's possible and doable. But maybe there is someting that prevents JS scope? Like iframe?

slot .. is this some sort of custom element? is that what you mean by "non standard elements"?

Yeahhh I updated to custom element @JaromandaX

If I make a snippet I get your slot if I do console.log(document.querySelector('.slds-form slot')); DL is not a custom element

There appears to me many iframes in on the page. However, this section I query is not within an IFrame. It's really fustrating me @VLAZ

Tip to try and understand this: figure out what the top most element you can match is, then try and examine why you can't go down. You can include your findings in the question. For example right now you are trying to match <dl> but if the HTML looks like <x><y><z><dl> </dl></z></y></x> see where above this you can get. Maybe it's <y> so , there would be something about <z>

@VLAZ Thanks. You are correct. As I mentioned this is a complex page and it does result in <x><y><z><dl> </dl></z></y></x>. I have managed to find matches. And managed to find the custom element that is not letting me query down to <dl> in this case you could say its <z>

Are you dealing with a component that uses Shadow DOM perhaps?

How can I tell if I'm dealing with compontent using shadow DOM?
I can spot the EXACT element thats causing me issue and have editted post.

This is why it's important to run through the [mcve] exercise: take your code, and throw away everything that isn't involved in the problem. E.g. reduce your webpage by removing bits at a time until you're either left with just that element and things still don't work, or at some point you remove something and suddenly your code does work. You just found an entry point into debugging the problem yourself.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The page I am querying is not my webpage haha. I tried to reduce it to minimum code.
